# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter'

Tags: java, web-services, spring, jaxb, marshalling

I am trying out a simple spring web service application. I have configured the application correctly but when i try access the wsdl file i get the following error:

```
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]

17:24:35,409 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/springWsTest]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'webservice'
17:24:35,419 INFO  [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) FrameworkServlet 'webservice': initialization started
17:24:35,428 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'webservice-servlet': startup date [Tue Jul 03 17:24:35 BST 2012]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
17:24:35,443 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/ws-config.xml]
17:24:35,541 INFO  [org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
17:24:35,595 INFO  [org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
17:24:35,655 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
17:24:35,691 INFO  [org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
17:24:35,699 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1445d3c: defining beans [testEndPoint,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0,org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.mapping.SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0,org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.dom.DomPayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.SourcePayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.XmlRootElementPayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.JaxbElementPayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter#0,org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema#0,serviceDefinition,marshaller,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@a32ba9
17:24:35,764 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1445d3c: defining beans [testEndPoint,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0,org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.mapping.SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0,org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.dom.DomPayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.SourcePayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.XmlRootElementPayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.JaxbElementPayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter#0,org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema#0,serviceDefinition,marshaller,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@a32ba9
17:24:35,837 ERROR [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.expression.TypedValue
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:467) [spring-webmvc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:483) [spring-webmvc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:358) [spring-webmvc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:325) [spring-webmvc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127) [spring-webmvc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:952) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:188) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.expression.TypedValue
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext.setRootObject(StandardEvaluationContext.java:85) [spring-expression-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext.<init>(StandardEvaluationContext.java:74) [spring-expression-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:124) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1299) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.evaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:224) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:311) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    ... 27 more
```

Here are my configuration files:

ws-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage"/>

    <ws:annotation-driven/>


    <ws:dynamic-wsdl id="serviceDefinition" portTypeName="myService"
                     locationUri="http://localhost:8080/springWsTest/webservice">
        <ws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/schemas/downloadMessageRequest.xsd"/>
    </ws:dynamic-wsdl>

    <bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="contextPath" value="com.mypackage"/>
        <property name="mtomEnabled" value="true"/>
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" 
         version="2.4">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/app-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>webservice</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/ws-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>webservice</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webservice/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>wsdl</extension>
        <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xsd</extension>
        <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

</web-app>
```

app-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:ws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"   
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd         
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd         
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd         
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd         
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>    
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage"/>  


</beans>
```

downloadMessageRequest.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:m="http://ws.mypackage.com" 
xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" elementFormDefault="qualified"
targetNamespace="http://ws.mypackage.com" 
attributeFormDefault="unqualified">


    <xs:element name="downloadMessageRequest">
        <xs:complexType/>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="downloadMessageResponse" type="m:downloadResponseType" />

    <xs:complexType name="downloadResponseType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="requestName" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="payLoad">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="messagePayLoad" type="xs:base64Binary" xmime:expectedContentTypes="application/octet-stream"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>


     <xs:element name="localDTMRequest">
        <xs:complexType/>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="localDTMResponse">
        <xs:complexType>        
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="localDTM" type="xs:dateTime"/>
            </xs:sequence>          
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>


</xs:schema>
```

### Edit

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>springWs</groupId>
  <artifactId>springWsTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>springWs</name>
  <description> </description>

    <properties>        
        <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.ws.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring.ws.version>
        <javax.servlet.version>2.5</javax.servlet.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <dom4j.version>1.6.1</dom4j.version>
        <xml.bind.version>2.2</xml.bind.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.ws.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>${xml.bind.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${xml.bind.version}</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>springWsTest</finalName>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/schemas</schemaDirectory>
                    <packageName>com.mypackage.ws</packageName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>   
        </plugins>

    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${findbugs.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includeFilterFile>findbugs.xml</includeFilterFile>
                    <effort>Max</effort>
                    <threshold>Low</threshold>
                    <includeTests>true</includeTests>
                    <findbugsXmlOutput>true</findbugsXmlOutput>
                    <findbugsXmlWithMessages>true</findbugsXmlWithMessages>
                    <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                    <excludeFilterFile>findbugs-exclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${checkstyle.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jdepend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <!-- JUnit reports -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire.report.version}</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <reports>
                            <report>report-only</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire.report.version}</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <id>integration-tests</id>
                        <reports>
                            <report>report-only</report>
                        </reports>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputName>failsafe-report</outputName>
                            <reportsDirectories>
                                <reportsDirectory>target/failsafe-reports</reportsDirectory>
                            </reportsDirectories>
                        </configuration>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                        <format>xml</format>
                    </formats>
                    <instrumentation>
                        <ignores>
                            <ignore>com/bt/bl/**/*Test.*</ignore>
                            <ignore>**/*Steps.*</ignore>
                            <ignore>**/*Story.*</ignore>
                        </ignores>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>com/bt/bl/**/*Test.class</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/*Steps.class</exclude>
                            <ignore>**/*Story.*</ignore>
                            <ignore>**/*jbehave*.*</ignore>
                        </excludes>
                    </instrumentation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <targetJdk>1.5</targetJdk>
                    <rulesets>
                        <!-- PMD rule sets -->
                        <ruleset>/rulesets/basic.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>rulesets/codesize.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>/rulesets/coupling.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>/rulesets/design.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>/rulesets/imports.xml</ruleset>
                        <ruleset>/rulesets/unusedcode.xml</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have **spring-expression** in your Maven dependencies ?

If you are not using Maven, check your WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: if he was using maven, this would be included automatically

Comment: I have updated the description with the POM file. Is spring-expression is required?

Comment: Do not exclude spring-beans and spring-core.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue where I missed spring-ws ,spring-ws-core in maven dependencies, and got solved once added.

Answer (score 0):

Clean build your project and make sure all jars are available